# iOS Application getting crash when creating csv file with too much data

Tags: objective-c, ios, csv

1) I'm trying to create **CSV file using NSMutableArray(array of array)** which I want to send as a mail attachment using MFMailComposeViewController.Following is code i have written for it -

```
//Export Data to excel
-(NSString*)ExportToExcelClicked
{
    dataToSend = @"";

@try {

    for(int cntHeader = 0;cntHeader< [NamesArray count];cntHeader++)
    {

        dataToSend = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@\n",dataToSend,[NamesArray objectAtIndex:cntHeader]];
        dataToSend = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\nAccount Number,Engine Number,Chasssis Number,Registration,Vehicle Type,Vehicle Model,Vehicle Make\n"];

        for(int cntData = 0;cntData< [appDelegate.arrEmailRepossessionDetail count];cntData++)
        {

            NSMutableArray *thearr = [appDelegate.arrEmailRepossessionDetail objectAtIndex:cntData];

            NSString *strVehicleDetail = @"";

            strVehicleDetail = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@,",strVehicleDetail,[thearr objectAtIndex:0]];
            strVehicleDetail = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@,",strVehicleDetail,[thearr objectAtIndex:1]];
            strVehicleDetail = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@,",strVehicleDetail,[thearr objectAtIndex:2]];
            strVehicleDetail = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@,",strVehicleDetail,[thearr objectAtIndex:3]];
            strVehicleDetail = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@,",strVehicleDetail,[thearr objectAtIndex:4]];
            strVehicleDetail = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@,",strVehicleDetail,[thearr objectAtIndex:5]];
            strVehicleDetail = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@,",strVehicleDetail,[thearr objectAtIndex:6]];

            dataToSend = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@\n",dataToSend,strVehicleDetail];
        }

    dataToSend = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n\n",dataToSend];
    return dataToSend;

}

}            

@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"NSException: %@", exception.reason);
}
```

}

***Code for mail attachment***

```
NSString *strCSVData = [self ExportToExcelClicked];

        if ([strCSVData isEqualToString:@""] || strCSVData.length > 0) 
        {
            NSData *dataObj = [strCSVData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        }
```

The problem is csv file is getting properly created for around 800 to 900 records,but beyond
that application is getting crash.Is there any efficient was to create csv record.

2) Also the csv file is displaying data properly in ***excel but not in open office***
eg:-

***Open Office output***
Account Number
19824:38:00

***Excel output(Expected output)***
Account Number
019465:021578

Can't understand why ***OpenOffice*** is not showing proper output.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely need to change your `dataToSend` instance variable to be of type `NSMuableString` and only append data to it. The way you do it now, creates a new string every time, but with `NSMutableString` it will only append it.

Comment: thanks graver you are right.Creating a new string is definitely not an efficient way.Will try code with NSMutablestring.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely your app runs out of memory.

You create lots of autoreleased objects. But because your code is a giant memory allocating loop it crashes before it reaches the end of the current runloop, where the automatically created autorelease pool is drained.

You should use your own [autorelease pool](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000047-CJBFBEDI). And, as graver pointed out, use NSMutableString and appendString. This will create less autoreleased objects that take up memory. 
And try to use only `appendString:`, not `appendFormat:`, parsing formats takes time and memory.

Probably something like this:

```
NSMutableString *dataToSend = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:10000]; // put your own estimate, based on the usual length of a data row and the number of rows

[dataToSend appendString:[namesArray objectAtIndex:cntHeader]];
[dataToSend appendString:@"\n\nAccount Number,Engine Number,Chasssis Number,Registration,Vehicle Type,Vehicle Model,Vehicle Make\n"];
for(int cntData = 0;cntData< [appDelegate.arrEmailRepossessionDetail count];cntData++)
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSMutableArray *thearr = [appDelegate.arrEmailRepossessionDetail objectAtIndex:cntData];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [thearr count]; i++) {
        // loop for the columns
        if (i > 0) {
            // put , before each column that is not the first column
            [dataToSend appendString:@","];
        }
        [dataToSend appendString:[thearr objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    [dataToSend appendString:@"\n"];

    [pool drain];
}
```

Comment: @Mathhias,Thanks your suggestion were really helpfull...it is working really efficiently now....